# C# move a Polyline

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, animation

I'm new in the graphical programming with C#. Yesterday I started one new project (WPF). There is a Polyline object which I have to move along the screen with coordinates which I'm calculating. I don't know how to move the object and make something like an animation. On mouse down I want to start this method `Move()` after that go into the while cycle and when the condition is completed `(end == true)` I want to end the cycle and complete the animation. And while I'm in the cycle my idea is to move my Polyline with slow movements. I tried to put `Move()` into a thread and use `Thread.Sleep(...);` but I could see just the end position not all way of the Polyline.
I tried to put it into `new Thread(new ThreadStart(Move));` ...and `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`, the effect was the same.
Could you tell me, please, how I can make this movement?

```
     public void Move()
     {
        bool end = false;
        while (!end)
        {
            double x = lastPosX;
            double y = lastPosY;

            double a = y1 - y;
            double b = x - x1;
            double c = -x * y1 + x1 * y;

            double u, v;
            GetC(out u, out v);                    

            if (y1 < lastPosY)
            {
                GetCoordinates(ref u, ref v);
            }

            if (u > width || v > height)
            {
                 gameEnd = true;
            }

            lastPosX = u;
            lastPosY = v;

            p.Points.Remove(p.Points.First());
            p.Points.Add(new Point(u, v));

          }

       }
```

Comment: Your code is confusing. How do you set "end" to true to exit out of the loop? Also, you are using many variables that we don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't quite able to figure out how your Move method works but here's an example of how you can move a Polyline from Left to Right upon MouseDown. Hopefully you'll be able to adapt it to your needs

**Xaml**

```
<Canvas Name="myCanvas">
    <Polyline Name="myPolyline"
              MouseDown="Polyline_MouseDown"
              Canvas.Left="75"
              Canvas.Top="50"
              Points="25,25 0,50 25,75 50,50 25,25 25,0" 
              Stroke="Blue"
              StrokeThickness="10"/>
</Canvas>
```

**Code behind**

```
private void Polyline_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    double left = Canvas.GetLeft(myPolyline);
    var animationThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        while (left < 300)
        {
            left += 10;
            // SetLeft is done in the UI thread
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(myPolyline, left);
            }));
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }));
    animationThread.Start();
}
```